# React Image Gallery by categories - trying to separate the image component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have 3 categories:
-Books
-Albums
-Movies

what I had: I had fetch and return in each component the same code (with different category, id and images), so basically decided to separate it to external component, everything works beside the url which for some reason I can't pass the variable "type" from grandparent to a grandchild and that's why images don't render. This is the code:

first child:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useFetch = (address, view) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState();


    const fetchData = async (view) => {

     await fetch(address)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        const data = json.map((elem) => {
          console.log(view)
          const imageUrl = `${view}${elem.id}`
          const newObject = {
            id: elem.id,
            title: elem.title,
            image: imageUrl,
          };
          return newObject;
        });
        return data;
      })

      .then((finalData) => {
        setError(undefined);
        setData(finalData);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error("Errors: ", e);
        setError(e);
      });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
  }, [address]);


  return {data}

}
```

parent:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useFetch } from "./useFetch"

function ImagesList({category, number, type}) {
  const address = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/${number}/photos`
  const {data} = useFetch(address)
  

    const view = type

  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="header__title"> {category}</h1>
      <h1 className="header__title"> {eleven}</h1>
      {/* {error && <p>Error!: {error.message}</p>} */}
      <main className="container">
      <div className="items-list" data-style="cards">
        {data.map((item) => (
            
            <div className="items-list__item item">
              <img className="item__img" src={item.image} 
              />
              <div className="item__info">
              <div className="caption">
              <h6 className="item__name text--center">{item.title}</h6>
              <div className="item__description">Statham stars as Arthur Bishop, a professional assassin who specializes in making his hits look like accidents, suicides, or the acts of petty criminals.</div>
              <p className=" heart d-inline-block"> <button>"To Favorites"</button> </p>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div>
              </div>
            </div>
          // </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ImagesList
```

and this is the main component (I have 3 of those total: Movies, Books and Albums, so I need to modify variables to pass them to the 2 above components)

the main one:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import "../styles/images.css";
import "../styles/favorites.css";
import ImagesList from "./ImagesList";

const Books = (category, number) => {


  return (
    <ImagesList category="Books" number="2" type="https://api.lorem.space/image/book?w=150&h=220&hash=$"/>
  );
}

export default Books;
```

Can anybody please help me? I am kind of stuck.

Thank you!

Comment: can you console.log your item.image and see what is its output?

Comment: Anthony, I am not sure how to do that :( I don't know where to type console.log, since item.image is declared in a return statement of the parent component, so whenever I type console.log in "return" part, my program breaks (((